# After adding a set of editable table rows to a showModalDialog, is there a way to pass the row(s) to a JSP?

Tags: html, jsp, showmodaldialog

Here is what I have and what I need info on:

1. I have an HTML `table` with `checkbox`es in one JSP.
2. When the user selects a `checkbox` and then hits the submit `button`, I open a `showModalDialog`<sup>([IE-api-doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536759%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), ([Firefox-api-doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.showModalDialog))</sup> screen.
3. I need to fetch the entire row and then display it on the `showModalDialog` as an editable field.

For example, I have a row with: `name`, `dob`, `employee id`, `office loc` and then a `checkbox`. When I select one of the rows, I am able to store the `rowid` as well as the row itself in a string.

How should I pass this to the JSP (where the `showmodaldialog` points to) and then make it into a editable row and display it on the screen? If the user selects 3 rows, all three rows should display as editable fields on the `showmodaldialog` screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JavaScript to find the selected employees, and compose a URL with the IDs of all the selected rows (3, 54 and 867 for example):

```
/foo/editEmployees?ids=3&ids=54&ids=867
```

Invoke `showModalDialog()` with this URL as argument.

In the servlet mapped to `/editEmployees`, use `request.getParameterValues("ids")` to get the IDs of the employees to edit. Get the information of these employees from the database and generate the HTML page containing the form to edit these employees.